# How do you make owasp zap crawl subdomains?

Tags: owasp, zap

In the spider window it says they are out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Include them [In Scope](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/scope/) by setting them as part of the [Context](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/contexts/) that you'll specify as the [starting point](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/spider/) for the [Spider](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/spider/) or [Ajax Spider](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/ajax-spider/).
Note: Contexts are defined with regex expressions so inclusion of sub-domains is easy.

Alternatively you could also proxy traffic, make manual requests, or spider those domains as starting points.

Comment: i didnt word my question clearly. I dont want to crawl the subdomain, I just want the spider to find them and add them tto the sites panel  while spidering a  domain. Burp suit does this. But zap doesnt.

Comment: and your point is? ZAP is able to do all of the core features of burp, just in a slightly different way. Just say you dont know how to do it in zap or dont say anything anything at all.

Comment: If the Spiders aren’t making requests to them they won’t be added to the Sites Tree or History. If you want them added, have the Spider(s) make requests to them as I already provided instructions. My point was if you wan burp behaviour use burp.

Comment: Okay first you can’t use zap, then you can’t ask a question clearly (or figure out how to use Edit), and now you’re popping off at the only person that bothered to answer/help. Brilliant!